# Uncaught (in promise): Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, three.js, angular-promise

I'm super new with promises, I'm trying to implement them but I have this error
`Uncaught (in promise): Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded` 
I'm also getting problem using Promise.all().then() because it expected one argument.
Environments: **Angular** v12 and **Three.js**
I hope that someone could help me, thanks in advance.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onPageLoad();
  }

  onPageLoad(options) {
    this.loadPromise();
 
    Promise.all().then(() => {
      this.resize();
      this.setupResize();
      this.addObjects();
      this.render();
    });
  }
```

```
loadPromise() {
    // Uncaught (in promise): Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded
    const fontOpen = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new FontFaceObserver("Open Sans").load().then(() => resolve);
      console.log('Output Playfair Display has loaded.');
    })

    const fonPlayfair = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new FontFaceObserver("Playfair Display").load().then(() => resolve);
      console.log('Output Playfair Display has loaded.');
    })

    // Preload images
    const preloadImages = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll("img"), { background: true }, resolve);
        console.log("Output img has loaded.")
    });

    let allDone = [fontOpen, fonPlayfair, preloadImages];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @danh thanks to answer me. I solved with your help the problem about the promises (code above), then I tried to change the default loading timeout in 6 seconds and I got this error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: 6000ms timeout exceeded` . So I think that increasing timeout doesn't change the result

```
async onPageLoad() {
    const promises = this.loadPromise();
    
    await Promise.all([promises]).then(() => {
      this.resize();
      this.setupResize();
      this.addObjects();
      this.render();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to improve in the code, one that will possibly (but maybe not) fix the exception.

The exception appears to be thrown by fontFaceObserver [whose docs](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) indicate that the default loading timeout is 3 seconds (3000ms). Perhaps try a longer timeout, as those docs suggest, with the optional second parameter to load.

Meanwhile, code improvements that are a must for the code to work at all...

```
onPageLoad(options) {
  const promises = this.loadPromise();  // assign the return value

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {    // pass it to Promise.all
    this.resize();
    this.setupResize();
    this.addObjects();
    this.render();
  });
}

loadPromises() {
  // we don't construct new promises here, because fontOberserver already returns promises
  const fontA = new FontFaceObserver("Open Sans");
  const fontOpen = fontA.load(null, 6000);  // try a longer timeout, but no guarantee

  const fontB = new FontFaceObserver("Playfair Display");
  const fonPlayfair = fontB.load(null, 6000);

  // I'm not sure what imagesLoaded returns. Assuming it's not a promise... 
  const preloadImages = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll("img"), { background: true }, resolve);
  });

  // this function must return the promises
  return [fontOpen, fonPlayfair, preloadImages];
}
```